# Why is memory not freed after a lottie-ios animation view controller is dismissed?

Tags: ios, lottie, ios-animations

I have a view controller with `AnimationView` (the class of `lottie-ios` pod). The animation takes too much memory (about 800 MB). But the problem is that,after the view controller is dismissed, the memory is still full.

The animation view is created as following:

```
var mainAnimation = AnimationView(name: "my_animation_name")
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem reason was that I used the old version of lottie-ios pod – 3.1.8. In the old version, the BundleImageProvider had the static cache property

`static var cache = [String: UIImage]()`

So even when all instances of `BundleImageProvider` are deinitialized, this property is still in memory because it's static. There is no clearCache method. And the property is not public. So I can't access it directly. In version 3.1.9, they removed this property, so the problem is solved.

**But if you still need to use the old version there is another solution**

The init of the AnimationView has `imageProvider: AnimationImageProvider` argument. The `AnimationImageProvider` is a protocol. If the passed property is nil the `BundleImageProvider` is used by default. You may create your own implementation of `AnimationImageProvider` and use it. You may copy the implementation of the `BundleImageProvider` and then do one of two actions:

1. make the `cache` property non-static
2. leave the `cache` property static, but add the `clearCache` method.
   I prefer the first one because you won't need to manually handle cache clear.